# tiny scrollbar when setting height to viewport it disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

css

```
/* Tiny Scrollbar */
#scrollbar1 { width: 559px; margin: 20px 0 10px; clear: both;}
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 500px; height: 1050px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#scrollbar1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#scrollbar1 .scrollbar{ background: transparent url(images/bg-scrollbar-track-y.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: relative; background-position: 0 0; float: right; width: 11px; }
#scrollbar1 .track { background: transparent url(images/bg-scrollbar-trackend-y.png) no-repeat 0 100%; height: 100%; width:9px; position: relative; padding: 0 1px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb { background: transparent url(images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-y.png) no-repeat 50% 100%; height: 20px; width: 20px; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; left: -5px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end { background: transparent url(images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-y.png) no-repeat 50% 0; overflow: hidden; height: 5px; width: 20px; }
#scrollbar1 .disable { display: none; }
```

when I set .viewport to more than 700px then the scrollbar doesn't show.  I don't get it.

PS. I didn't post code because I am using as is straight from the demo, but just in case:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar({ size: 360 });; 
    });
```

Ok I just tried another scroll jscrollpane and same thing happens.  Here's the [site](http://iminds.pe/headhunters/noticia2.html) so you can see what I am trying to do. Right now it doesn't show the rest of the content and if I change it to 1050px it will but the scroll is gone.

I am in a bind if there is anymore code that I could give let me know I don't know what else to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You using a image set the height and width of the image. The scrollbar cant calculate the metrics of the viewport correctly because when its initialized the image is still loading.

Comment: so I did that but it shows up to where the image finished and the rest of the text is gone(hidden)..

Comment: Your font color is set to white.  Check the body css style.

Comment: yea it's because thats an iframe that sits in another page where the background is dark, but that's not the issue.

Comment: Hi Andres, i have just gone through your problem but i m bit confused can you pls specify what exactly you want to achieve? what is 700px width or height in viewport and where you are setting 1050px width or height?